# Read json data from properties file

Tags: java, json, properties

I have a JSON data in the properties file and trying to retrieve it in java. When I am trying to retrieve the JSON data with the property name it's giving only first string/word from the JSON.

Inside the property file, I have the below content.

```
profile:  {"fname": "ABC","lname": "XYZ","meetings":{"morning":10,"evening":60}}
```

I am trying to read the content using property name 'profile' as a string and I am getting below error message.

```
Expected ',' instead of ''
```

can someone help me with the issue, I tried to escape and unescape but still have the same issue

Comment: can you show your code snippet where you are fetching profile value?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what you are using to deserialize the JSON, but well formed JSON is a single element, so what you have needs to be inside of a container. That is, your file content should be:

```
{ profile: {"fname": "ABC","lname": "XYZ","meetings":{"morning":10,"evening":60}}}
```

Comment: the profile does not belong to the JSON, its a property in the property file and assigned with the above JSON.

Comment: I see, I must not have understood your question well, do you think you could post more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
profile={"fname": "ABC","lname": "XYZ","meetings":{"morning":10,"evening":60}}
```

Or if you want to do it in multiple lines

```
profile={\
  "fname": "ABC",\
  "lname": "XYZ",\
  "meetings":{\
     "morning":10,\
     "evening":60\
  }\
}
```